# Facebook graph 100% width og

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, width, fluid

I am setting up facebook video with my service and i have the following facebook graph in the head.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="614180238680567"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Title goes here"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $poster; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Powered By Service"/>
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="800">
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="600">    
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"> 
        <meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo $m4v; ?>">
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="<?php echo $m4v; ?>">
```

As you can see i have set a width of 800 and height of 400 the probelm is when the video is viewed it does not fill the space and is very small i can inspect element and add a 100% width and it fits perfectly.

Can someone let me know if this is possible with facebook graph or how i can span the video across the post space.

Example here. https://www.facebook.com/s3bubble

Thanks

Comment: Looks full width to me.

Comment: Hi wizkid thanks for the response so if you click play on the video it spans right across the post space?